# What are the requirements of a function so that the left Riemann sum equals the right Riemann sum?

Tags: riemann-sum

My homework question in particular specifies over an interval of [0,1], the function is negative, and the function is decreasing.

Comment: What is a "right" or "left" Riemann Sum??

Comment: @DonAntonio Presumably a Riemann sum in which one takes the value of the function at the right or left endpoints of the subintervals.

Answer (score 0):

Given: $\Delta x = \frac{b - a}{n}$, when no limits are involved we can expand the left and right Riemann sums as follows:

\begin{align*}
R_L &= \sum_{k = 0}^{n -1} f(a + k\Delta x) \Delta x = f(a) +\sum_{k = 1}^{n -1} f(a + k\Delta x) \Delta x \\
R_R &= \sum_{k = 1}^{n} f(a + k\Delta x) \Delta x = f(a+ n \Delta x) + \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} f(a + k\Delta x) \Delta x  \\
\end{align*}

If $R_L = R_R$, then their difference should be zero:

\begin{align*}
R_L - R_R &= 0\\
\left(f(a) +\sum_{k = 1}^{n -1} f(a + k\Delta x) \Delta x\right) - \left( f(a+ n \Delta x) + \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} f(a + k\Delta x) \Delta x\right) &= 0 \\
f(a) -  f(a+ n \Delta x) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

Therefore, the left and right Riemann sums are the same, without limits, when the following holds true:

$$f(a) = f(a + n \Delta x)$$

When limits are involved, the left Riemann sum approaches the right Riemann sum, as $n \to \infty$.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} R_L &= \lim_{n \to \infty} R_R \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Isn't the requirement for non-limit situations much looser, namely that the left and right ends must be equal?

Comment: @DanUznanski I might be overlooking something. Can you explain what you mean by the left and right ends?

Comment: $R_R - R_L = \sum_{k=1}^{n} df(a+kd) -\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} df(a+kd) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} df(a+kd) + df(a+nd) - (\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} df(a+kd) + df(a+0d) = d(f(a+nd)-f(a))$ so equality is when $f(a+nd)=f(a)$

Comment: @DanUznanski You are right. Do you want to submit this as an answer, or should I edit this into my answer?

Comment: Think it belongs in yours

Comment: @DanUznanski No problem. Thank you for that!